# Maven compile does not create class files

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a 3 module maven project with parent pom. From parent when I run a maven clean-compile-test. It fails at test phase and gives tons of compilation errors saying "symbol not found" for my local classes.

I discovered using **IntelliJ ide** if I use the "Make Project" button **before** I run a maven test, then maven test works!

**Edit:** Now I figured out that probelem is maven compile does not create class files in target folder for some reason this is my maven compiler plugin configuration in parent pom file:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>

                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you could post your pom.xml-files.

Comment: Are there possibly any snapshot dependency updates containing the missing classes?

Comment: @Uwe Allner I updated the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maven doesn't care about missing symbols in the `package` phase; missing symbols will only be reported during the `compile` phase (= when the Java compiler is run by Maven).

To find out why it can't find the symbols, you need to examine one of the errors. Look into the folder `target` and check if the missing class exists in there (at the right place).

`mvn clean` deletes this folder but `mvn compile` should put new files in there.

If you can't see anything obvious, then save a list of all the files in the `target` folder somewhere. Then build the project in IDEA. Again create a list of all files.

Sort both lists and then compare them. That might give you an idea what is wrong. My guess is that you configured Maven in an odd way (moving source folders or target folders).

**EDIT** The configuration

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
</excludes>
```

tells Maven "ignore all source files" which is equivalent to "don't do anything". Remove this and try again.

Comment: tnx clean compile works fine, problem happens on maven test. a test classes can not find other java classes and give symbol not found error

Comment: and yes compile does not create the classes in target folder, but "make project" does, my maven compile plugin is not configured well?

Comment: tnx, thats embarrassing!

Comment: could you also have a look at this? tnx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23541364/maven-can-not-create-javadocs

Answer (score 23):

One more thing.

Look in pom.xml, tag `<packaging>`. If it sets in `pom`, Maven shouldn`t create class-files for you. Change it for appropriate package - `jar`, `war` ...