# Maven: Can not create Javadocs

Tags: java, maven

I can not create javadocs to a folder I like, Here is how my javadoc plugin looks like;

```
 <build>

            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${build.dir}/resources/javadoc</outputDirectory>
                <reportOutputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/javadoc</reportOutputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT MAven install leads to error"

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:aggregate
  (attach-javadocs) on project priTool: An error has occurred in JavaDocs report     generation:
 [ERROR] Exit code: 1 -            C:\pricing\priWebApp\src\main\..webapp\backend\local\PriUpgradeHelper.java:5:
 package       ..upgrademanager does not exist
[ERROR] import ...upgrademanager.ComponentInfo;
```

Upgrade Manager is an external dependency, but I can see its jar in library

Comment: What output do you get when you run `mvn install`? Is there an error?

Comment: @Aaron Digulla YESS! When I do a clean compile install, it can not find hunderds of classes and symbols

Comment: Unless the `${build.dir}` is an internal property of your project, you should be using the `${project.build.directory}` property, or any other [standard Maven property](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide).

Comment: Show us the first error.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla I updated

Comment: `mvn depencency:tree` shows Upgrade Manager as one of the dependencies? Is there a `upgrade-manager-${VERSION}-javadoc.jar` in your local Maven repository?

Comment: @Aaron Digulla I couldnt run maven tree goal on all modules with success, on priwebapp it fails because it can not find the dependency priEngine

Comment: also no such thing as ...javadoc.jar

Comment: I suggest to fix the missing dependency first. That might help solve the other issues.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla it says Failure to find com.ch.pri:priEngine:jar:0.2-SNAPSHOT in http://mavenrepo.ch.int/repo was cached in the local repository,

Comment: thats the dependency of other module(jar file), it should not look for external repo for that I guess?

Comment: Did you `mvn install` this module?

Comment: @Aaron Digulla wow it worked now! but I thought all I need is to run a clean compile package from the parent pom, do I need to run individual mvn install goals per module in advance?

Comment: No, that's not necessary if everything is configured correctly. You should be able to run mvn clean install from the parent. If you can't, then you have problems.

Comment: @Engineer Dollery look like it is necessary in my case cause it didnt work until intall the child, and I need to know what the configuration problem is in this case

Comment: @Spring: `mvn package` doesn't install the JAR, so the next module which depends on it can't find it. Unless you know exactly what you're doing, you should never use `mvn package`. Always use `mvn install`. If you use it in the parent, it will install the parent and all the children. No need to run it on each child manually.

Comment: @Aaron Digulla tnx but if I run from parent, install I get error :Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.9.1:aggregate (attach-javadocs) on project priTool: An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - C:\pricing\priWebApp\src\main\java\ch\pricing\webapp\backend\local\PriUpgradeHelper.java:5: package com.upgrademanager does not exist
[ERROR] import nl.chess.it.upgrademanager.ComponentInfo;

Comment: @Aaron Digulla this error goes away if I install priEngineModule before parent install

Comment: post all your poms and we may be able to help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between `mvn package` and `mvn install`. `package` creates the JARs in the `target` folder of the Maven project/module.

If there are more modules, they won't be able to see these JARs - for each project/module, Maven **only** looks into the local repository to resolve dependencies, even if could resolve them in the same project.

And that's what `install` does: Package the JARs and then install them into the local repository.

When you have a Maven project, with several modules (a.k.a a reactor build), then **never** use `mvn package`. **Always** use `mvn install`.